# Добавление новой строки в JTable по кнопке (Java) (Swing)

Tags: java, swing

Да,вопрос от новичка.Не нужно издеваться.

Есть таблица JTable [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В красных областях ( это было нарисовано в paint) необходимо добавить три кнопки :

1. Добавить - по нажатию этой кнопки должна появиться новая строка.
2. Сохранить - слушатель событий я сам привяжу,но нужно сделать так,что если где-то оказалась пустая ячейка,по нажатию чтобы он выбросил диалог "Есть пустые поля! Проверьте все поля!", а куда сохранять и т.д. это я сам сделаю. Это не сложно.
3. Удалить - удаляет выбранную строку.

Я пытался полистать учебник с менеджерами размещений и добавлением кнопок, не получается найти нужное мне.

Модель таблицы вот :

```
    TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
    table.setModel(tableModel);
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();

    table.setModel(model);
```

Способ удаления строки вот :

```
     int sel = 0; // или номер строки или getSelestedRow
     model.removeRow(sel); // удаление выбранной строки
```

Просто создавал таблицу и программу путем поиска различных кусков кода в интернете,а в этой части не получается кнопки добавить.

Comment: почему игнорируют тему?

Comment: я создавал свою модель имламентируя интерфейс - сам "настроил" методы и таблица ведет себя так, как я хотел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JPanel p2 = new JPanel();

p2.add(new JButton("Выполнить")); 
p2.add(new JButton("Отменить")); 
p2.add(new JButton("Выйти"));

frame.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```